# How to drag & drop a link to the Favorites bar in Microsoft Edge

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge, bookmarks, favorites

I'm able to drag & drop an HTTP link from a webpage to the favorites bar of IE11, Chrome, & Firefox, but it doesn't work on Microsoft Edge.

Is this a native limitation or is a way to perform it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply drag the padlock icon on the left of the URL to your favorite bar. It could have been a problem with an earlier version.

[image: padlock icon]